# Expect condition not working in a script without error

Tags: shell

I'm running a script to update DB password on my instance. But, it's not working and not seeing any error. Just wanted to check the script looks good.
Expect is not working.

```
expect -f - <<-EOF                                                        
spawn sudo su hxeadm                                                     
expect "New HANA database master password: "                               
send "XXXXXXX\r"                                                         
expect "Confirm \"HANA database master\" password: "                       
send "XXXXXXX\r"                                                         
expect "Proceed with configuration? (Y/N) :"                               
send "Y\r\n"                                                             
expect eof                                                                  
EOF
```

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow.com.
You should add more description to your question, not just paste the script and ask to check it.
Also please format the code.

Comment: I'm running above script to update DB password on my instance.  But, it's not working and not seeing any error.  Just wanted to check the script looks good above steps